# Using Beautiful Soup and Selenium to Insert Data into CSV

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using `beautifulsoup` and `selenium` to scrape some data in python. Here is my code which I run through the url `https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/YwbnUyDn/#/match-summary/point-by-point/10`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DRIVER_PATH = '$PATH/chromedriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

class_name = "matchHistoryRow__dartThrows"

def write_to_output(url):  
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find_all("div", {"class": class_name}))
    return
```

This is the schema I am trying to scrape- I would like to get the pair of spans between the colons and put them into separate columns on a csv, the problem is the `class` comes either before or after the colon, so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. For example:

```
<div class="matchHistoryRow__dartThrows"><span><span class="matchHistoryRow__dartServis">321</span>:<span>501</span>
        <span class="dartType dartType__180" title="180 thrown">180</span></span>, <span><span>321</span>:<span
            class="matchHistoryRow__dartServis">361</span><span class="dartType dartType__140"
            title="140+ thrown">140+</span></span>, <span><span
            class="matchHistoryRow__dartServis">224</span>:<span>361</span></span></div>
```

I'd like this to be represented this way in a csv:

```
player_1_score,player_2_score
321,501
321,361
224,361
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to parse the scores (the easiest method, if the text is structured accordingly):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<div class="matchHistoryRow__dartThrows"><span><span class="matchHistoryRow__dartServis">321</span>:<span>501</span>
        <span class="dartType dartType__180" title="180 thrown">180</span></span>, <span><span>321</span>:<span
            class="matchHistoryRow__dartServis">361</span><span class="dartType dartType__140"
            title="140+ thrown">140+</span></span>, <span><span
            class="matchHistoryRow__dartServis">224</span>:<span>361</span></span></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# 1. parse whole text from a row
txt = soup.select_one(".matchHistoryRow__dartThrows").get_text(
    strip=True, separator=" "
)

# 2. find scores with regex
scores = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s+:\s+(\d+)", txt)

# 3. create dataframe from regex
df = pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=["player_1_score", "player_2_score"])
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
  player_1_score player_2_score
0            321            501
1            321            361
2            224            361
```

---

This crates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

Another method, without using `re`:

```py
scores = [
    s.get_text(strip=True)
    for s in soup.select(
        ".matchHistoryRow__dartThrows > span > span:nth-of-type(1), .matchHistoryRow__dartThrows > span > span:nth-of-type(2)"
    )
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"player_1_score": scores[::2], "player_2_score": scores[1::2]}
)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *Selenium* and [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) for ***player_1_score*** you need *`span:first-child`* and for ***player_2_score*** you need *`span:nth-child(2)`*. So you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.co.uk/match/YwbnUyDn/#/match-summary/point-by-point/10')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
player_1_scores = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.matchHistoryRow__dartThrows span span:first-child")))[:3]]
player_2_scores = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.matchHistoryRow__dartThrows span span:nth-child(2)")))[:3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(player_1_scores, player_2_scores)), columns=['player_1_score', 'player_2_score'])
print(df)
```

Console Output:

```
  player_1_score player_2_score
0            501            321
1            361            321
2            361            181
```

To write to a *CSV*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(player_1_scores, player_2_scores)), columns=['player_1_score', 'player_2_score'])
df.to_csv("my_data.csv", index=False)
```

Snapshot:

[image: panda_csv]